# How does amp analytics affect multiple sessions on the same property?

Tags: google-analytics, sitecore, amp-html

Essentially, I'm concerned that a single user can be counted twice.   Is there a best practice, etc.  I've tried googling and I'm not sure if I'm just not asking the right question with the right words.  Platform is on sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same property to track AMP and non-AMP pages will result in multiple users. [See here for Google's recommendation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/#amp_vs_non_amp_traffic).

Though looks like you can use the [Google AMP Client ID API](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7486764) to work around this.